# Integral Method used in matlab

Tags: matlab

Which method is Matlab using for the command `integral`? Why is it always returning 0 if I want to integral a normal distribution with mean far away from 0, i.e. I shift the curve to very far point away from 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `integral` command just calls the `integralCalc` method. The integration method used mentions in source code:

```
%INTEGRALCALC  Perform INTEGRAL calculation.

%   Based on "quadva" by Lawrence F. Shampine.
%   Ref: L.F. Shampine, "Vectorized Adaptive Quadrature in Matlab",
%   Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics 211, 2008, pp.131-140
%
%   Strong algebraic singularities are handled with a technique from
%   L.F. Shampine, "Weighted Quadrature by Change of Variable", Neural,
%   Parallel, and Scientific Computations 18, 2010, pp. 195-206.
```